# Catch user input error in real-time

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, user-input

I made this simple console app which requires user to input a username and password.
The data are then saved in a Db. For each column in Db I assigned a limited number of values for the data type. For example, the password (`varchar(5)`) must have max 5 characters.

```
using System;

namespace MyConto
{
    public class NewUser
    {
        public static void NewUserRegistration()
        {
            Console.Write("Username: ");
            string user = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Password: ");
            string pass = Console.ReadLine();     
        }
    }
}
```

Now, how can I make a real-time (??) check on what user writes in console ? It's even possible ?
For example, a message which warn the user if he write `"password"` as password that the string is too long.

Thanks

Comment: `if (pass?.Length > 5)`

Comment: @mjwills ok, but this will give the user the message that he is doing wrong ? I already thought about this and also about a try/catch but it's ugly to see in console...

Comment: try/catch is allways ugly, you should avoid it if possible. In your case it *is* possible. Simply check if more than five characters were provided and if so print a message, e.g. using `Console.WriteLine("Too long")`.

Comment: `but this will give the user the message that he is doing wrong ?` Consider using `Console.WriteLine` to write the message to the end-user.

Comment: A password with max. five characters? Why do you even have any if it is so short?

Comment: @HimBromBeere it's just a mockup/test. Of course real ones will be much longer..

Comment: This question seems a bit confusing to me. The OP keeps using the phrase "real-time" which, to me, indicates he'd like to check as they are typing for errors. If that is the case, the answer becomes simply, no this is not possible. The Windows command shell does not evaluate a command line until the enter key is pushed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by 'in real-time' you mean you *don't* want the user to press ENTER before seeing the message - so as soon as they type a 6th character it tells them it's too long.  you cannot do this with Console.ReadLine()  You *could* do this with Console.ReadKey() instead, though this is a lot of effort... but just for fun:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //First clear the screen.  We need to have absolute knowledge of what's on 
        //the screen for this to work.
        Console.Clear();
        //hide the cursor as it has no real bearing on much....
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        var user = GetLimitedInput("UserName?", 0, 10, true);
        var password = GetLimitedInput("Password?", 4, 5, false);

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine($"User is {user} and password is {password}");
    }


    private static string GetLimitedInput(string prompt, 
        int lineToShowPromptOn, int maxChars, bool showChars)
    {
        //set cursor to the suggested position
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, lineToShowPromptOn);
        //output the prompt.
        Console.WriteLine(prompt);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, lineToShowPromptOn + 1);

        var finished = false;
        var inputText = string.Empty;

        while (!finished)
        {
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                //remembr old input so we can re-display if required.
                var oldInput = inputText;
                var key = Console.ReadKey();
                //check for CTRL+C to quit
                if (key.Modifiers.HasFlag(ConsoleModifiers.Control) && key.KeyChar=='c')
                {
                    inputText = string.Empty;
                    finished = true;
                }
                //allow backspace
                else if (key.KeyChar == '\b')
                {
                    if (inputText.Length > 0)
                    {
                        inputText = inputText.Substring(0, inputText.Length - 1);
                    }
                }
                //check for return & finish if legal input.
                else if (key.KeyChar == '\r')
                {
                    if (inputText.Length<=maxChars)
                    {
                        finished = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //really we should check for other modifier keys (CTRL, 
                    //ALT, etc) but this is just example.
                    //Add text onto the input Text
                    inputText += key.KeyChar;
                }

                if (inputText.Length > maxChars)
                {
                    //Display error on line under current input.
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, lineToShowPromptOn + 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("Too many characters!");
                }
                else
                {
                    //if not currently in an 'error' state, make sure we
                    //clear any previous error.
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, lineToShowPromptOn + 2);
                    Console.WriteLine("                     ");
                }
                //if input has changed, then refresh display of input.
                if (inputText != oldInput)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, lineToShowPromptOn + 1);
                    //do we show the input?
                    if (showChars)
                    {
                        //We write it out to look like we're typing, and add 
                        //a bunch of spaces as otherwise old input may be        
                        //left there.
                        Console.WriteLine(inputText+"            ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //show asterisks up to length of input.
                        Console.WriteLine(new String('*', inputText.Length)+"            ");
                    }

                }

            }
        }

        return inputText;
    }       
}
```

Note: this has lots of flaws, but it's just for illustrative purposes :)

Comment: It's perfect for educational purpose because of comments here and there.
I can't just copy paste it but I will for sure consider it in the future. Good job.

Comment: @Link - I always try to comment the WHY in any examples I put anywhere...  otherwise it's not helping people to learn anywhere near as well.   I just thought I'd put it together for a quick little challenge...  I wouldn't necessaily recommend this approach (very much re-inventing the wheel!), though if you want to mask passwords when inputting via a console app you'd probably have to do something like this.  That said, I'd be surprised if there isn't a library somewhere which handles this far more elegantly than my hacked-together example!

Answer (score 2):

Add a validate method like:

```
private bool isValid(string input)
{
   //my validation logic
}
```

And use like:

```
  ...
string user = Console.ReadLine();
if (!isValid(user))
{
    ///my logic for warning the user that input is invalid
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep asking the user until he gives a valid password you can do something like this:

```
string ObtainPassword()
{
    string password;
    string passwordErrorMessage;
    while(true)
    {
        Console.Write("Password: ");
        password = Console.ReadLine();
        passwordErrorMessage = ValidatePassword(password);
        if (passwordErrorMessage == null)
            return password;

        Console.WriteLine($"\r\n*** {passwordErrorMessage}");
    }
}
```

The password validation method would be like:

```
string ValidatePassword(string password)
{
    if(password.Length > 5) return "Password is too long";

    //Add other validations here as needed

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Consider using `password?.Length` in case the password is `null`.

Comment: Actually OP wants to verify password is max. 5 characters long, because the column in the db has `varchar(5)`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Ok, that was just an example, but fixed, thanks.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I am also curious about another thing: in db I set `varchar(5)`. But it's strange that even if the user input a pass long 10 chars it will not show any error...
Maybe I am missing something..

Comment: You still have to change the error-message into `"Password is too long"`, haha.

Comment: Damn X-D Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
using System;

namespace MyConto
{
    public class NewUser
    {
        public static void NewUserRegistration()
        {
            Console.Write("Username: ");
            string user = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Password: ");
            string pass = Console.ReadLine();
            while (pass.Length > 5)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Insert a valid password (max 5 chars)\n");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                Console.Write("Password: ");
                pass= Console.ReadLine();
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`do { ... } while()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do), to call `ReadLine()` once for `pass`.

Comment: Also, this will allow an empty password - which may be desirable of course, just a thought

Comment: Consider using `pass?.Length` in case the password is null